# How can I customize a menu to be intuitive for my users: show user name, have dropdown items

Tags: routes, users

I am looking to create a user menu. The menu when not logged in should have two options: 1. create account 2. sign in. These items will be displayed in-line.

Once logged in, I want the menu to have two options: 1. account name 2. sign out

When logged in the "account name" menu item will have a drop down with menu items linking to the various user tabs present in the user backend.

Information: I am working with a theme I downloaded. The main menu has a fairly extensive dropdown function but I do not know how it is doing it. If I could figure that out then I could apply that to the user menu for the function I want.

The reason I want this done: I had a potential customer loose interest and leave my site because he could not figure out where he could download his files from. So I figured I needed to create a easy to understand user menu.

Thanks for your help!

Drupal 7
link to my website: sonikloops.com

Answer (score 5):

This can be easily done with the available following contributed modules.

- Create menus from Admin UI, and restrict the visibility by [Menu Per Role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) module. Here, you might like to to show the menus *Create Account* and *Sign In* only to anonymous (not logged in) users.
- You can use the [Menu Token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module, if you wish to show username as menu. You'll need to install the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module and the [Ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module in order to do this. This can be done in following way:

  1. Create a menu link in your User menu using Admin UI by visiting `http://yoursite.url/admin/structure/menu/manage/user-menu`.
     [image: snap1]
  2. In the link title you input the user name. The following will replace the `[current-user:name]` with the username of the logged in user. You can even use other fields, under the "Menu Token Options" > "Replacement Patterns".
     [image: snap2]
  3. The output of the above:
     [image: snap]
     As admin:
     [image: snap4]
     As an authenticated user:
     [image: snap5]
- For the dropdown feature of the menu, you can use the [DHTML Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu) or the [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) menu.

Hope that helps. Please feel free to ask questions.

Comment: thanks for the info! #1 helps. Sometimes i get so bogged down in how open Drupal is i forget to check the simple things =-)

Comment: #2 i have been searching for a few hours and everyone seems to be saying the same thing, "Menu token module." i did isntall it and have no idea how to use it. I read the documentation but that is showing how to link it to a view, which ended up confusing me more. could you explain to me how to use it?

Comment: #3 if my site already has drop down funciton, do you think i should replace that function with a module? or keep its function the way it is? it might be java, or it might be a module, im not sure.

Comment: @TimJones sorry for the late reply. See how to user tokens in Menu title in the edit for #2.  
And about #3 I'm not aware how your theme implements the menu (CSS3/JavaScript/jQuery ?), so I'm not in a position to suggest any solution.