# How change "user menu" to current username

Tags: theming

I'm looking for a way to change the label "user menu" to be the current user's username. I am using the default Drupal 7 theme, Bartik, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do that with [hook_preprocess_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7)

e.g, in template.php

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars){

  global $user;
  $block =& $vars['block'];

  if ($block->module == 'system' && $block->delta == 'user-menu') {
    if (user_is_logged_in()) {
      $block->subject = check_plain($user->name);
    }
  }

}
```

[Clear theme registry cache](http://drupal.org/node/173880#theme-registry) after adding new preprocess function.

Comment: I actually have a subtheme. I created a file called templates.php and template.php and tried the code but it doesn't change. I deleted the cache per your instructions too. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you rename "mytheme" to your theme name.

Comment: Still nothing, does this file just sit directly in my subtheme's folder? Should it be named template.php or templates.php?

Comment: template.php in your subtheme folder, clear all caches at admin > performance > clear caches. If that doesn't work, try copying block.tpl.php from base theme to sub theme folder and clear cache again.

Comment: @keith, please try again, I had &= vs =& around the wrong way for the assignment by reference. Answer corrected.

Comment: upvote especially for using check_plain, and not t() in $block->subject :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Menu Token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module along with the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module to achieve this.

> Menu Token module provides tokens, that could be used in title or in path of menu items (links).

A detailed step by step procedure to achieve the use case can be found at the [answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/49762/6461).

Answer (score 1):

No need for Menu Token; as long as you have the Token module enabled, just set the User Menu Block title to `[current-user:name]`