# Menu token. Problem with [current-user: name]

Tags: navigation, 7

I saw [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49761/how-can-i-customize-a-menu-to-be-intuitive-for-my-users-show-user-name-have-dr/49762#49762), but how to make that anonymous user does not see this menu link "anonymous"?

[image: menu link for Anonymous user]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check permissions and make sure anonymous users don't have access to that page (or set of pages, content type)

Comment: the fact that the link leads to a page /user

Comment: what? that's neither a question or proper statement - not sure what you're saying

Comment: I have a menu. there is a link in the menu, I want to do with the token [current-user: name]. I installed the module Menu Token and made it. Registered user sees your name, but unregistered user sees "Anonymous". I want to unregister user does not see the link at all.

Comment: depending on your setup, it shouldn't show in the menu if the user doesn't have permission to that page

Comment: how can I restrict access to the page /user for unregistered user?

Comment: try restricting access for viewing user profiles

Comment: try that. and obviously remove the login info from your previous post (even presuming you delete the user). Changed /user to /[current-user:url] - permissions handled the rest as expected